# Java 11 webstart-maven-plugin subtitude

Tags: java, maven-plugin, jnlp, openwebstart

I need to replace my webstart-maven-plugin plugin version to make it work on Java 11.

Actual version

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
</plugin>
```

As I understand, this plugin does not work with Java 11, could you make any suggestions of replacement for the plugin.

Im getting this error:

```
A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-7:jnlp-download-servlet: Lorg/codehaus/mojo/keytool/KeyTool;
```

I'm working with Open Webstar, but I can't find any Maven plugin to create the jnlp files.

- I tried adding this dependency to the plugin but i got the same error:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>keytool-api</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

- I tried to update the webstart-maven-plugin but it doesn't work.